# SplitAt 3 and then keep on splitting

Tags: string, haskell, split

I want to split a string in Haskell every 3 letters along.

I have tried using `splitAt` but I would have to repeat this until the string is split every 3 letters along.

Is there a way to do this?

E.g

`"WEAREDISCOVERED"` would become `["WEA","RED","ISC","OVE","RED"]`

Comment: actually nevermidn this works:

Comment: chunk :: Int -> [a] -> [[a]]
chunk _ [] = []
chunk n xs = first : chunk n rest where (first, rest) = splitAt n xs

Comment: `takeWhile (not.null) . unfoldr (Just . splitAt 3) $ "QWERQWER"` does what you want. `unfoldr` is defined in `Data.List`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
everyThree :: [a] -> [[a]]
everyThree [] = []
everyThree xs = begin : everyThree remain
   where (begin, remain) = splitAt 3 xs
```

So this will work for any type of list including strings.  So if the list is empty we just return an empty list.  Otherwise we `splitAt 3`. Fortunately, `splitAt` is smart and will return just one, two, or none if the remaining list is too short.  Then we append that beginning string to the head of the remaining `everyThree` list.

Answer (score 4):

```
import Data.List.Split (chunksOf)

everyThree :: [a] -> [[a]]
everyThree = chunksOf 3
```

Nowadays Data.List.Split is part of the Haskell Platform.