# Split string to substring

Tags: haskell

I want to create function that split string to list of substrings where each substring have length of k:

```
*Main> split_string_to_kmers "some_text" 3
["som","ome","me_","e_t","_te","tex","ext"]
```

Here is my solution:

```
split_string_to_kmers s k = split_string_to_kmers_helper s k []
    where split_string_to_kmers_helper [] k acc = acc
          split_string_to_kmers_helper s  k acc
            | length s >= k = split_string_to_kmers_helper (tail s) k (acc ++ [(take k s)])
            | otherwise = acc
```

I am just wondering if there is a way to rewrite my code so it will be more haskell specific.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SplitAt 3 and then keep on splitting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19568178/splitat-3-and-then-keep-on-splitting) on I guess this is slighly different

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess this slightly different enough.

```
import Data.List (tails)

mySplit :: String -> Int -> [String]
mySplit str k = filter (\s -> length s == k) $ map (take k) (tails str)
```

You could make this more efficient by combining the filter and the map.  But that is up to you.

Answer (score 3):

Simple solution is next (not the same tail of list):

```
import Data.List.Split(chop)

splitRepN n = chop (\xs -> (take n xs,tail xs))
```

And we have next results:

```
> splitRepN 3 "some_text"
["som","ome","me_","e_t","_te","tex","ext","xt","t"]
```

And we cut short tails for full solution:

```
splitRepN' n = takeWhile ((== n). length) . splitRepN n

> splitRepN' 3 "some_text"
["som","ome","me_","e_t","_te","tex","ext"]
```